# Username with System.User

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10

Today I wanted to greet the user in my app by name, but I did not manage to get it.

I found `System.User`, but lacking some examples I did not manage to get the info I needed. I saw no possibility to get the current user (`id`) to call `User.GetFromId()`.

Can you guide me into the right direction? Have I been on the wrong path?

Comment: Do you mean that you've got a User object but can't figure out how to find a name from it, or that you can't figure out how to get a User object representing the current user?

Comment: I was talking about not getting an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, So first things first, getting access to a user's personal information is a privilege you have to request, so in your store app's Package.appxmanifest, you'll need to enable the `User Account Information` capability in the Capabilities tab.

Next, you'll want to be using the Windows.System.User class, not the System.User (System.User isn't available to Windows store apps, which you appear to be discussing given the tags you provided for your question)

Third, you'll want to request personal information like this.

```
IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser, UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated);
User user = users.FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null)
{
   String[] desiredProperties = new String[]
   {
      KnownUserProperties.FirstName,
      KnownUserProperties.LastName,
      KnownUserProperties.ProviderName,
      KnownUserProperties.AccountName,
      KnownUserProperties.GuestHost,
      KnownUserProperties.PrincipalName,
      KnownUserProperties.DomainName,
      KnownUserProperties.SessionInitiationProtocolUri,
   };

   IPropertySet values = await user.GetPropertiesAsync(desiredProperties);
   foreach (String property in desiredProperties)
   {
      string result;
      result = property + ": " + values[property] + "\n";
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
   }
}
```

When you call GetPropertiesAsync, your user will get a permission prompt from the system asking them if they want to give you access to that. If they answer 'No', you'll get an empty user object (but you'll still get a unique token you can use to distinguish that user if they use the app again).

If they answer yes, you'll be able to get access to the properties below, and various others.

See the [UserInfo Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo) Microsoft provided for more examples.

Comment: The documentation for `FindAllAsync` doesn't say anything about the first match necessarily being the current user.  Will this code actually work if more than one user is logged on at the same time?

Comment: it'd probably be worthwhile testing the behavior on something like terminal server, perhaps, but so far as I know, the flags UserType.LocalUser, UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated should ensure that it returns a local user. Of course, I'm not sure how this behaves with remote desktop either, and if that counts as Remote or Local. Oddly, there didn't seem to be a "user that ran this app" static property anywhere.

Comment: I should probably also add that the API is likely made with the xbox in mind, where it's possible to have multiple users authenticated at once locally, so it's probably worth while accounting for it